# WindowsFormsHost and DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, binding, prism, windowsformshost, dependency-properties

I've got a Windows Forms control that I'm attempting to wrap as a WPF control using the *WindowsFormsHost* class; I would like to bind the legacy control to a view-model. Specifically, the control exposes a grid property, *GridVisible*, that I would like to bind a view-model to. I'm using a private, static backing field and a static, read-only property to represent the dependency property (functionally the same as a static, public field, but less mess). When I attempt to set the control's *GridVisible* property via XAML, it's not updating. Ideas? What am I doing incorrectly?

### DrawingHost Class

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides encapsulation of a drawing control.
/// </summary>
public class DrawingHost : WindowsFormsHost
{
    #region Data Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the disposal flag.
    /// </summary>
    private bool disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the grid visible property.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly DependencyProperty gridVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridVisible", typeof(bool),
        typeof(DrawingHost), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the pad.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly DrawingPad pad = new DrawingPad();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set whether the grid is visible.
    /// </summary>
    public bool GridVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(GridVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridVisibleProperty, pad.GridVisible = value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the grid visible property.
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty GridVisibleProperty
    {
        get { return gridVisibleProperty; }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Default-construct a drawing host.
    /// </summary>
    public DrawingHost()
    {
        this.Child = this.pad;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose of the drawing host.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">The disposal invocation flag.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !disposed)
        {
            if (pad != null)
            {
                pad.Dispose();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Drawing.DrawingView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Drawing">
<local:DrawingHost GridVisible="True"/></UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first rules of dependency properties is to never include any logic in the get and set except the `GetValue` and `SetValue` calls. This is because when they are used in XAML, they do not actually go through the get and set accessors. They are inlined with the `GetValue` and `SetValue` calls. So none of your code will be executed.

The appropriate way to do this is set up a call-back using the `PropertyMetadata` parameter in the `DependencyProperty.Register` method. Then in the call-back you can then execute any extra code.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie! I specified an assignment callback and it works as expected.